# Trying to add User Role in res.user module of odoo-14 but it starts to show the groups in list view under access rights tab , any corrections?

Tags: python, forms, odoo, user-roles, odoo-14

[res.user form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdGwT.png)

> This is the code that i added to create the groups and category, everything worked fine only the view of form became list view as shown in the image.

```
 <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_user">
    <field name="name">User Role Management</field>
    <field name="description">Category of User</field>
 </record>

<record id="group_user_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Department Manager</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_user" />
</record>

<record id="group_user_agent" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Agent</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_user" />
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

These was not an error in fact it was just that ,the module was not getting fully updated when i updated the module from terminal,but when i updated the module from apps store of odoo then it started to show in perfect manner in the form. I think this is a glitch of odoo-14 since in previous versions it used to fully update from terminal as well.

[form view of user when updated from apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbW2u.png)